# Sql function that should error but instead creates successfully

Tags: sql, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm debugging a larger script and narrowed it down to the fact that a function is being created when it should error.

I tested the following function which SHOULD fail:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ShouldFail( @x INT )
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @i INT

SELECT @i = id FROM dbo.IDontExist
RETURN @i
END
```

Instead the creation succeeds.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, stored procedure and function definitions can be created with references to tables which do not exist. If you want to prevent this behavior, use the `SCHEMABINDING` option, which will cause an error to be raised if the referenced table is not found:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ShouldFail( @x INT ) 
RETURNS int
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE @i INT

SELECT @i = id FROM dbo.IDontExist
RETURN @i
END
```